# Read data from other activities

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-intent

How to read data from onther activity ?
I have 3 activitiews A, B and C
A (have 3 EditText and 1 Button) , B (have 3 CheckBox and 1 Button) and C have a Recyclerview

When the user in Activity B and select the checkbox he want then press the Button i need to collect the data from Activity B ( where I am in now) and collect the values of Edit Texts from ( activity A which is not opened ) and pass all values to activity C.

How to make this Scenario in Android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain good practices that you can follow here -

1. No fragments talk to each other. fragments are independent unit of UI and leave them to be that way.
2. If an activity has a fragment, then data passing can be done in this manner -

   a. From Activity to Fragment, use a static method on the Fragment class to put as many arguments as you want. Those arguments would be passed back as part of the bundle in `onCreate()`

   b. If the fragment has to pass some data back to Activity, then define a callback and let Activity implement the same and set it to the Fragment.

   Note : If you create a Fragment in Android Studio, using one of the Menu templates, both these things are exhibited in the generated template.
3. If you wanna pass data between Activities, then bundles and extras in the Intent are the way. `OnActivityResult` is another way to send data back from a launched activity to the activity which launched it.

Let know if this answers your question ?